# flutter facing the issue using Audioquery package?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter facing the issue when using the queryAlbum in Audioquery package there is no uri in this queryAlbum.so how to play song in queryAlbum? please help.

this my code.

```
              return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate:
                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                          crossAxisCount: 2),
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    final model = albummodels![index];

                    final id = model.id;
                    final name = model.album;
                    final artist = model.artist;
                    final length = model.numOfSongs;

                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (ctx) => Albumsonglist(
                                  albumname: name,
                                  artistname: artist,
                                  albumlength: length,
                                  id: id,
                                )));
```